# matplotlib graphs doesn't appear without show() method

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, plot, spyder

In many tutorials I have seen that to generate a plot, running `pyplot.hist` or `pyplot.plot` is enough but in my case I have to add `pyplot.show` no matter what, in order to see the results. I am writing my codes in Spyder IDE on Mac OS X. How should I take care of this problem?

An Example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
X=[1,2,3]
Y=[2,3,8]
pyplot.plot(X,Y)
```

P.S.: First I have compiled it myself and installed the libraries manually and now even when I installed it through DMG+Anaconda the result is the same!

Comment: Please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). It's hard to help without one.

Comment: Try adding `pyplot.ion()` just after importing `pyplot` and you should be able to avoid the `show()`...

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) How did you install Spdyer? With our DMG, Anaconda or MacPorts? Also, please provide an example that's not working for you to test it ourselves.

Comment: @SaulloCastro, thanks but didn't work.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba, I compiled it myself.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba, Any suggestions? I even tried installing it through Anachonda+DMG! Same problem!

Comment: What do you mean by Anaconda+DMG? I know this can be confuse but they are two different installation options. Our dmg (which you can download from our [website](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/downloads/list)) comes with the latest version of matplotlib preinstalled and doesn't have the problem you posted.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba I installed `Anaconda` and then downloaded the `spyder-2.2.5.dmg`(After uninstalling the spyder and the libraries that I manually installed) and still doesnt show anything. The point is when I run the code, a new spyder instant opens up and before showing anything it gets closed. Same as the time when I plotted with my own compiled spyder! No difference!

Comment: Then I don't know how else I could help you. Our dmg is totally self-contained and shouldn't show any issue. Maybe the libraries you installed to compile matplotlib in the first place are the ones that are giving you trouble. I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior depends on backend and on the interpreter you are using. For instance, I use ipython in pylab mode on OS X with matplotlib 1.3.0 and graphs appear right away.

Otherwise you might use interactive mode by invoking `pyplot.ion()`.

Comment: this also doesn't work! the ion() I mean. I tried standalone Spyder, Anaconda, Canopy but no chance!